# How do I keep the HERE MAPS / [Here-API] from expiring?

Tags: api, maps, here-api

I wish to use the here api on site but the credential for calling the api expires in 24 hours. Is there any other alternative long term solution that doesnt require client side refresh of the token every time the user wants to use the API ?

I'm told If I verify my account, the time to expire will get longer. I have a account with UN/PW and just talked to HERE Maps. One guy doesnt know what this means, so is this true?

Comment: Our credentials only expire if you don't confirm your email address. Did you do that?

Answer (score 0):

Several APIs require obtaining a token, valid during 24 hours. My solution consists in checking in a local database for a valid token, if there is no token (the first time there won't be any, of course) and then get a new one to be immediately store in the database.